# Combining geometry Overlay Expressions in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, overlapping-features

I have 2 shapefiles that cover a similar region, a river catchment and a hex-grid of surface water bodies within the catchment. The catchment has subcatchments, and I'm trying to link the hex-grids that overlay each sub-catchment in a column in the attribute table.

Using the geometry expressions in the Field Calculator in QGIS 3.28.4 LTR, I have got an expression that covers hexes that lie within (`overlay_within`), but I also want to include the hexes that Overlap (`Overlap`) in the expression.

I've been using the QGIS Documentation to understand the expression I want to write ([Select By Location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#id51) and ['Overlay_' geometry expressions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id92)), but my results only show the ones within, the ones that cross, or the ones that intersect, not only the first two that I want.

I've illustrated what I mean;
[image]

I want the expression to list in the hex-grid attribute table that Circle 1 AND Circle 2 are spatially connected to the Orange Box. Circles 3 and 4 would be spatially connected to Box 2.

At the moment I only have 2 separate expressions

`array_to_string(overlay_within('Box',Box_ID))`
which returns

| Circle ID | Connected to Box_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Box 1 |
| 2 | *NULL* |
| 3 | *NULL* |
| 4 | Box 2 |

I can't have NULL values for shared-overlapping circles (hexes), because then they won't be factored in at all for later spatial operations.

`array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Box',Box_ID))`
which returns

| Circle ID | Connected to Box_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Box 1 |
| 2 | *[Box 1, Box 3]* |
| 3 | *[Box 1, Box 2]* |
| 4 | Box 2 |

I can't have arrays or multiple spatial relations for one Circle (Hex) because that will cause issues later down the line.

`overlap` I found I couldn't use because I couldn't get it to include only the Box_ID attribute, just the entirre shapefile name (i.e. All the Circles are connected to 'Boxes.shp').

What I want is just `overlay_within` and `overlap` (or `intersect` minus `touch`) that produces this result below with

| Circle ID | Connected to Box_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Box 1 |
| 2 | Box 1 |
| 3 | Box 2 |
| 4 | Box 2 |

How would I construct the expression for what I'm specifying, or is this a multiple and separate expression operation?

Comment: Does using the centroid will work ? In your exemple the centroid will be the center of the circle (so circle 2 centroid will fall in box 1) but with very irregular feature you may get case where the centroid fall in the wrong box

Comment: @J.R I'm using identical sized hexes, so the centroids might work! I'll figure out if I can do that on a per-hex basis within the Field Calculator and then I can try that with ```overlay_within```.

Comment: So I've tried ```array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Box_Layer', Box_ID, centroid($geometry)))``` and while it does check out, it only returns a Null values for all features.

Similar results with ```array_to_string(overlay_contains('Box_Layer', Box_ID, centroid($geometry)))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
overlay_intersects('Box_Layer', Box_ID, sort_by_intersection_size:='des')[0]
```

This code will get all intersecting boxes ID's and sort them in an array by size of intersection with descending order (biggest intersections first). Then [0] index takes first array's element - it's the box with biggest common area with the circle.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it appears to have the same issue - The syntax checks out within the Field Calculator, but it only produces NULL results. Similar if I repeat it with ```array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Box_Layer', Box_ID, sort_by_intersection_size:='des')[0])``` or if I put double quotes around the Box_ID (```"Box_ID"```).

Does it matter very much if the Box ID of the Box and Circle's 'Box_ID' attribute is an integer?

Comment: Update: I accidentally used the wrong layer without the Box_ID set, hence the Null Value. This actually worked perfectly! Thank you very much.